# Transition from simple past to present perfect

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

This is a part of my self introduction:

> I taught English and Arabic, and this has led me to the decision that I have to give translation a try.

What I mean to express is that I have recently considered my past career, which leads me to this "novel" decision that I want to try my hand at translation.

Does this transition from simple past to present perfect follow the correct use of English tenses? And does it convey what I mean to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty good already, but I would write something like:

"I have previously taught both English and Arabic, and this has led me to deciding that I wish to start doing translation too."

The latter part reads a bit more positively than your original, so is better for an application letter. If instead you were writing for a blog-post or something informal like that, then that part of your original was fine.